# How do I identify an element in Protractor on a non angular page?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm new to Protractor. I'm using Jasmine and Visual Studio Code.
I have the following on my non angular page to be tested for 2 different buttons:

```
<span id="2-1-9294160_2_1_" class="PlaceBet Bet" onclick="addSingleBetToSlip(event);" bet-event-id="2-1-9294160" bet-event-number="1117" bet-event-startdatetime="2020/02/11 10:48:00" bet-event-starttime="10:48" bet-event-typename="DashingDerby" bet-marketclassname="Place" bet-selectionid="1" bet-odds="2.16" bet-display-description="1. Chilli Bean">2.16</span>

<span id="2-1-9294693_1_4_" class="WinBet Bet" onclick="addSingleBetToSlip(event);" bet-event-id="2-1-9294693" bet-event-number="1129" bet-event-startdatetime="2020/02/11 11:36:00" bet-event-starttime="11:36" bet-event-typename="DashingDerby" bet-marketclassname="Win" bet-selectionid="4" bet-odds="3.79" bet-display-description="4. Gladiator">3.79</span>
```

The only unique elements that I can use are:

```
bet-event-typename="DashingDerby"
bet-marketclassname="Win" 
bet-selectionid="4"
```

How do I find/click these elements in Protractor?  I've tried all of the following, but it's giving error messages:

```
    //element(by.bet-selectionid('4'), by.bet-marketclassname('Place')).click();
    //browser.driver.findElement(by.bet-selectionid('4')).click();
    //element.span(by.bet-selectionid('4')).click();
    //element(by.css('.bet-selectionid > span'('4'))).click();
    //element(by.xpath("//span[.bet-selectionid('4')")).click();
    //element(by.tagName('.bet-selectionid('4')')).click();
    element(by.css("#bet-selectionid('4')")).click();
```

Comment: This is not a "non angular page" issue.

Answer (score 0):

In [async](https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await) function:

```js
let element = element(by.css('[bet-selectionid="4"]'));
await element.click();
```

I suggest you to take a look at [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. I've come right with the following after you've directed me in the right direction:

```
browser.wait(function() { 
return element(by.css('[bet-event-typename="DashingDerby"][bet-marketclassname="Place"][bet-selectionid="9"]')).isPresent(); 
}, 5000); 

element(by.css('[bet-event-typename="DashingDerby"][bet-marketclassname="Place"][bet-selectionid="9"]')).click();
```